# Stored Procedure randomly stopped working after 7 years

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I work for a hedge fund and our database system recently began acting up. I did some investigating, implemented error codes as well as message boxes between each process. I finally came upon exactly where the problem lies: it seems to be in the stored procedure in SQL.

We are using VB 2005, Access for SQL table views, and Microsoft Server Management Studio Express on Windows XP SP3.

Every other process is working. Here's how it works:

We fill a transaction from bloomberg which creates a .csv file. This .csv file gets put into a SQL table called BBGT_Transactions. It's a direct copy. This process works perfect. The transactions are in there every time the process is run (every 30 minutes). Next, the same process takes the transaction in BBGT_Transactions and copies it to Transactions. The call from VB looks like:

```
 Public Sub CopyNewEMSTransactions()

        Log.Info("Copying new transactions from BBGTransactions to Transactions")
        DAL.sqlcmd("CopyNewEMSTransactions")

End Sub
```

CopyNewEMSTransactions is a stored procedure which looks like:

```
USE [IPAS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CopyNewEMSTransactions]    Script Date: 10/28/2013 13:34:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Name
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyNewEMSTransactions] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

--New Code: Accounts for option trades through bloomberg terminal
INSERT INTO Transactions (Account, TDate, [Time], SDate, Class,
                              [Type], Ticker, Quantity, Price, SEDOL,
                              CUSIP, Comments, OrderNumber, ISIN)
    SELECT TranAccount AS Account,
           (SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(ExecDate AS float)) AS datetime)) AS TDate,
           ExecDate + ExecTime - '1899-12-30' AS [Time],
           ExecDate + 3 AS SDate, CASE EMS.Broker
                                    WHEN 'CIBC' THEN 'Equity'
                                    WHEN 'CIBO' THEN 'Option' END AS Class,
          CASE Side
            WHEN 'SS' THEN 'SHORT'
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'BUY'
            WHEN 'S' THEN 'SELL'
            WHEN 'BS' THEN 'BUY'
            ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
          END AS Type, EMS.Ticker,
          CASE Side
            WHEN 'SS' THEN -1
            WHEN 'S' THEN -1
            WHEN 'B' THEN 1
            WHEN 'BS' THEN 1
          END * FillAmount AS Quantity, 
          AveragePrice AS Price,
          SEDOL, CUSIP,
          Comments = 'Bloomberg data',
          LatestRows.OrderNumber, ISIN
    FROM    
        (SELECT Ticker, OrderNumber, MAX(ExecSeqNumber) AS LastExecSeqNumber
        FROM BBGTransactions
        WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM Transactions 
                                  WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data')

        GROUP BY OrderNumber, Ticker) LatestRows
    LEFT JOIN
        --Changed from "SELECT * From BBGTransactions" to add the ' Equity'
        (SELECT BBG_ID, ExecDate, ExecTime, TranAccount, 
            CASE Broker
                WHEN 'CIBC' THEN Ticker
                WHEN 'CIBO' THEN Ticker + ' Equity' END AS Ticker,
        --With option trades, SEDOL is not used anywhere. It used to be used for the Reconciliation report
        --but that report has been changed to look at option ticker instead.
        CASE Broker
            WHEN 'CIBC' THEN SEDOL
            WHEN 'CIBO' THEN NULL END AS SEDOL, 
        CUSIP, OrderNumber, Side, FillAmount, AveragePrice, ExecLastFillPX, Broker, Currency, OrderType, 
        LimitPrice, DayFillAmount, DayAvgPrice, ISIN, Amount, ExecType, ExecSeqNumber, ExecPrevSeqNumber FROM BBGTransactions) EMS
    ON LatestRows.LastExecSeqNUmber = EMS.ExecSeqNumber
       AND LatestRows.OrderNumber = EMS.OrderNumber
    WHERE LatestRows.OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM Transactions 
                              WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data')

END
```

It returns no errors and displays "Copying BBGT to Transactions Table", then "Done" but doesn't copy!! It worked for 7 years, and stopped working about 3 weeks ago.

Things to keep in mind:

- For the last month we have had very intermittent internet
- I suspect windows updates were run and windows was not updated for ~3+ years before this. There were 70 updates the last time I checked and now there are none.
- Going back to a ghost is my last resort as that will require a lot of work on my end to implement
- NO CODE WAS CHANGED EVER!
- I have tried running ONLY the stored procedure and it does nothing, as suspected.

**EDIT**
Got a tracer log, running only the procedure. It returned no errors though?

```
SELECT SYSTEM_USER
go
SET ROWCOUNT 0 SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647 SET NOCOUNT OFF SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON SET ARITHABORT ON SET LOCK_TIMEOUT -1 SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 0 SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED SET ANSI_NULLS ON SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON ON SET ANSI_PADDING ON SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go
select @@spid select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')
go
USE [IPAS]

go

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CopyNewEMSTransactions]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value


go
exec sp_execute 18,5930,5924,5925,5926,5927,5928,5929,5923,5921,5922
go
exec sp_execute 16,59826,59827,59756,59757,59758,59716,59715,59700,59701,59702
go
```

Also, the corresponding excel table:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ce76EHd.png]

Link, incase it's hard to see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJFRo.png

---

Select statement #1 (seems to be working):

```
SELECT Ticker, OrderNumber, MAX(ExecSeqNumber) AS LastExecSeqNumber
FROM BBGTransactions
WHERE OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM Transactions
                          WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data')
GROUP BY OrderNumber, Ticker
```

Return:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6z0T.jpg]

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6z0T.jpg

Select 2:

CODE:

```
SELECT BBG_ID, ExecDate, ExecTime, TranAccount,
    CASE Broker
        WHEN 'CIBC' THEN Ticker
        WHEN 'CIBO' THEN Ticker + ' Equity' END AS Ticker,
    --With option trades, SEDOL is not used anywhere. It used to be used for the Reconciliation report
    --but that report has been changed to look at option ticker instead.
    CASE Broker
        WHEN 'CIBC' THEN SEDOL
        WHEN 'CIBO' THEN NULL END AS SEDOL,
    CUSIP, OrderNumber, Side, FillAmount, AveragePrice, ExecLastFillPX, Broker, Currency, OrderType,
    LimitPrice, DayFillAmount, DayAvgPrice, ISIN, Amount, ExecType, ExecSeqNumber, ExecPrevSeqNumber 
    FROM BBGTransactions
    WHERE LatestRows.OrderNumber NOT IN (SELECT OrderNumber FROM Transactions
                                         WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data')
```

ERROR
Server: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "LatestRows.OrderNumber" could not be bound.

Comment: Run the stored procedure with the "actual execution plan" option enabled and see what steps affect zero rows unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I go about this?

Comment: If BBGT_Transactions is a temp table, you'll have to run the two procedure in the same session to work when testing. Is it possible that bloomberg changed their file format?

Comment: They haven't! First thing I checked :)

The output file is first copied into BBGT transactions (which works). What's not working is copying the data from BBGT transactions into Transactions. Both are databases in SQL.

Comment: Have any security patches or other updates been applied to the system since the last time you ran this?  Also, is there sufficient space on the disks you're writing to?

Comment: After seven years, has the database .mdb file reached 2GB in size?

Comment: The thing is, the DB file being written to gets written to by another process within VB itself. It's still able to write to the table so the table cant be full....

@Joe: Im pretty sure windows updates ran and we have microsoft security essentials running as well

Comment: Run the bits either side of your join in your procedure to see if your query separately come back with any data and see if they come back with any data in common.

Comment: @PHils - you may be trying to write a block of data too large for the table to hold. The other process may be doing 1-2 rows, where this one may be doing 500 or 1000 and it cannot fit them. The other process may stop working eventually too.

Comment: Is the database engine MSSQL or MSAccess? I am not clear based on your description.

Comment: @stingyjack: it's MSACCESS and it's only trying to write 1 line in this instance, and never more than 4 (we aren't high frequency)

Comment: Take the SELECT statement out of that proc and put it in a query analyzer window and see if it runs, and what results are present. When I have these problems, I start commenting parts of where clauses and then Joins to find out where my records are getting filtererd.

Comment: The Excel table is of no help to us, only the SQL Tables matter for the stored procedure.  Go into Management Studio, connect to your SQL Server database and execute the following two commands: `SELECT Count(*), Count(Distinct(OrderNumber)) FROM Transactions  WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data'` and `SELECT Count(*), Count(Distinct(OrderNumber)) FROM BBGTransactions` and tell us the results.

Comment: @Stingyjack: does the log not help?

Comment: @Phils It cannot be Access, that Stored Procedure can only run on SQL Server.  You may be using Access as an interface/front-end, but the data engine must be SQL Server or the stored procedure never could have run.

Comment: @rbarryyoung you're right! Access is the viewer, and 2005 SQL server management studio express is used for SQL

Comment: @rbarryyoung

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: @Phils somethings not right, those are valid SQL statements, I just tried them to be sure. Check them again and try them one at a time. If they still fail then post a screenshot, because somethings definitely off about that.

Comment: Is `Transactions.OrderNumber` a non-nullable column? If it's nullable, are there any records with a null value? A `NOT IN` clause breaks if there's a null value inside, so if a bad record snuck in that table, your whole query would be empty.

Comment: @phils - looks like rbarryyoung is on the right track. The first and most obvious check is to see if that `SELECT` Statement is actually returning any rows. Any chance you could try to run the SQL Statement starting with: `SELECT TranAccount AS Account` and ending with ` WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data')`

Comment: @Phils - no, typically the log does not help as quickly as deconstructing the query does. Start taking out parts of the query until you find the part that is the problem. What everyone is alluding to is that its the data does not now match what the query is expecting.

Comment: @StingyJack thanks, I've run the 2 selects. The results are in the post.. seems the 2nd one isn't running properly

Comment: The first query produces no results. This is likely the problem, there are only records that match this... SELECT OrderNumber FROM Transactions WHERE Comments = 'Bloomberg data'

Answer (score 2):

You work for a hedge fund, get the standard license and don't use the freebie.

It doesn't look like you posted the actual stored procedure, but a "cleaned up" version to show how it works.  That is actually a hinderance, not a help.

It's hard to say at this remove, but I would say you have either a data problem (the query runs exactly as it is always has, but the data you have doesn't return any results), or you have finally exceed the limitations built into the express version.

Forget about running the SP, extract the queries and run them directly, getting a feel as to what the data actually looks like.  If the select works but not the insert, you may have exceed the limitations of the express version.  If the select doesn't return the expected rows then you have a data issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
-I have tried running ONLY the stored procedure and it does nothing.
```

What do you expect it to return? does it show any affected rows?

```
NO CODE WAS CHANGED EVER
```

**Are you sure the schema didn't changed?** did you try running the query and see for yourself if it's valid? (run the select without the insert command from the SP)

**Are you sure you are using the correct database?** this could change too..

**Are you sure that your VB code actually finishes?** I would try printing logs after the SP is executed, there might be an exception here that we don't see.

Comment: Absolutely nothing was changed in the code. I am 100% sure of this as I'm the only one with access to the actual code.

The database is correct, we don't have many and again the code was not changed and neither were the database names (otherwise none of the other code would run and it does)

The VB code does finish. I created a message box to display "DONE" when its finished, and we have console log as it's running. I can see it running the stored procedure and when it's done as well.

Also, I tried running just the stored procedure and it says it ran but nothing changes.

Comment: @Phils - I believe you :) things can change in the environment also. this is basic things I would start from checking, and adding logs will get you close to finding your solution.

Comment: Thanks Yosi. Sorry if I came across rude, was not my intention, your answer is definitely helpful. 

The thing about printing actual logs... I tried to implement a real log file but it won't print to the log so I gave up and continued using the console and msg boxes. It created the log file but leaves it empty?

Comment: @Phils - No prob, if you want to be sure that it finished, you'll have to print the log right after the SP finished (there might be code that catches this exception). are you 100% sure of that?

Comment: I'm working on creating a trace, though I'm running into issues. We're using 2005 SQL server management studio express

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't do "Random".. 
Something has changed which is causing the unexpected results. stepping through the code is the only way to know for sure..